# Audio icon isn't working, but keyboard buttons are

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, taskbar, services

### Problem

My speakers work fine and they are able to play any sounds, from music to anything, like normal.
Except, the taskbar icon shows that it is unusable (see below)...

Yet, the volume (or whether it's muted) can be controlled using the sound buttons.
And, I can't use the troubleshooter because it just comes out with an error.

### System information

**Operation System**: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit
**Audio Driver:** IDT High Defination Audio CODEC (*May not be an actual driver.*)
**Laptop Type:** DELL Latitude E6230

---

### Screenshots

1. The taskbar showing that something is wrong with my audio.

   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. The sound buttons found at the corner of my DELL Latitude E6230.

   [image: Screenshot 2]
3. Problem with troubleshooter.

   [image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: @ayimothy If you're comfortable doing this, I'm curious to know what happens if you uninstall the device from `Device Manager > Audio inputs and outputs` and `Device Manager > Sound, video and game controllers`, deleting the drivers completely if given the option, then reinstalling them.

Comment: Nothing happens. But - I did found out that all you needed to do is refresh explorer (after restarting the drivers) because like registry policies - They don't refresh until you actually kill (end the task) explorer.exe and then reopen it.

Comment: I've tried doing above after restarting my computer and it did not work... There seems to be another problem... Starting/killing/restarting the audio drivers and services didn't work either... But the audio mixer works fine. Just the icon that isn't.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Not sure what to try next :(